# Python type checker mypy: subprocess.STARTUPINFO is not defined

Tags: python, mypy

When using [subprocess.STARTUPINFO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) etc. mypy complains:

```
error: Name 'subprocess.STARTUPINFO' is not defined
error: Module has no attribute "STARTUPINFO"
error: Module has no attribute "STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW"
error: Module has no attribute "SW_HIDE"
```

<strike>Is this because of https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1990?</strike> Edit: Is this because it's missing [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/5af337b43829ab3ba6ba41eccbcd0bcaace08831/stdlib/3/subprocess.pyi#L374)?

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your hunch is correct: those constants appear to be missing from typeshed.

You should file an issue on the typeshed repo or perhaps even just make a pull request and just add them yourself. If you get them in quickly enough, those changes might be accepted in time for the next mypy release, which I believe is this Friday. (If not, those changes will be a part of the next release, which will be in roughly a month from now?)

In the interim, you can likely suppress those errors via some combination of `# type: ignore` and by configuring how mypy handles imports. See:

- http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html
- http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html

...for details.

Alternatively, you could clone typeshed, modify it locally, and instruct mypy to use your local copy of typeshed via the `--custom-typeshed-dir` command line argument.

Comment: Looks like it [got fixed in typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/2041), but [will not be included](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4839#issuecomment-381104316) in today's mypy release yet.
`# type: ignore` didn't work for me.